# How to add miktex pdflatex to PATH

Tags: path

On my windows company machine I would like to setup LaTeX with Emacs. When I try to compile a .tex file I get the following error:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `report' with ``pdflatex  -file-line-error    -interaction=nonstopmode "report.tex"''
'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I found this question on this forum. That is why I have tried to add the location of miktex bin folder to path in my `init.el`:

```
;;;; TEXT MODE
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
(add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/")
```

However after restarting emacs I don't see it added to the PATH, `M-x getenv Ret PATH Ret` leads

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python39\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\blp\DAPI;C:\blp\DAPI\DDE
```

What am I doing wrong to get the emacs recognize miketex's pdflatex?

Comment: Try `(setenv "PATH" (concat "Write its directory down here" path-separator (getenv "PATH")))`

Comment: @Shynur worked, many thanks! if you put it as an answer, I will gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't see it added to the PATH

It is because `exec-path` is a variable in the Emacs Lisp world.

`C-h v exec-path`:

> a variable defined in ‘C source code’.

Whereas `PATH` is not a concept from Lisp.

They are **different** things.

---

> How to add miktex pdflatex to PATH

Use `setenv` to modify it (and other *environment variables* as well):

```lisp
(setenv
 "PATH" (concat "Write its directory down here"
                path-separator
                (getenv "PATH")))
```

There is one place worth noting; that is `path-separator`.

For portability, its value depends on platforms.
On MS-Windows it is a *semicolon*.

My advice is to never write it by hand.

---

You can also find relevant and useful information on [*李杀(Xah Lee)*'s website](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_env_var_paths.html).